Diode Connected PMOS Doesn't Fully Activate
I'm very new to electrical and am trying to understand a diode connected PMOS. I am supplying 3.3V to the source and have tried varying loads after the drain of 220, 10k, 100k, 650k, 1.2M ohms. What I have observed is that more resistance causes a higher voltage measured after the drain. At 1.2M ohms I measured roughly 2V on Vd.
This does not make sense to me. Why would I measure a higher voltage with more resistance? And why is the voltage not 3.3V? I would expect the lowest 220 ohm resistor to pull the Vg low and fully open the PMOS.


With the drain and gate tied together (same circuit node), you can't simultaneously pull the gate low and see a high voltage on the drain. If you separate them, you'll see the behavior you describe.

With 3.3 V as your maximum gate-source voltage, most P-channel MOSFETs aren't going to be more than very slightly on even with zero resistance there.

The diode connected MOSFET is not a perfect diode. It is roughly a diode with the gate-source-threshold voltage as the forward drop.
As any other diode, less current makes it drop less voltage. This is why a larger series resistor (less current) reduces the voltage drop across the MOSFET.
